# Ensuring Exclusive File Access for Multiple Servers in S3 Bucket Processing

Tags: file, amazon-s3, parallel-processing, locking

In an S3 bucket, I have about 100k small files. I want to implement a system where multiple servers can access and process these files. The goal is to ensure that each server selects a unique file from the bucket, reads it, and deletes it without two servers simultaneously processing the same file.

How can I guarantee that each server running concurrently selects a unique file from the S3 bucket to process without any overlap or duplication in file selection among the servers?